# Вывод из базы в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, framework

есть таблица с домашними заданиями `homeworks`:

```
id
replay
```

и таблицы с ответами, которых может быть несколько для одного дз `homework_answers`:

```
id
id_homework
replay
```

как мне в шаблоне вывести к каждому дз несколько ответов:
вот я вывожу список домашних заданий?
вот так я только вывожу одно дз

```
$done = DB::table('homework_answers')
                ->leftJoin('homeworks', 'homework_answers.id_homework', '=', 'homeworks.id')
                ->leftJoin('schedules', 'homeworks.id_shedule', '=', 'schedules.id')
                ->leftJoin('relations', 'schedules.id_relation', '=', 'relations.id')
                ->select('homework_answers.answer','homework_answers.basename', 'homework_answers.created_at','homeworks.replay', 'schedules.theme', 'homeworks.file','homeworks.filename', 'homeworks.dateofdelivery')
                ->where('relations.teacher', $id)
                ->where('relations.learner', Auth::user()->id)
                ->where('homeworks.status', 2)->orderBy('homeworks.id', 'asc')->get();
```

в шаблоне вот так

```
@foreach($done as $iteme)
      <div class="item">
          <p class="title">{{ $iteme->theme }}</p>
          <div class="data-content">
             <div class="left">
                 <div class="text">{{ $iteme->replay }}</div>
                      <a href="{{ $iteme->file }}">{{ $iteme->filename }}</a>
                 </div>
             <div class="right all">
                 <div class="date-block">Дата сдачи: {{ $iteme->created_at }}</div>
                     <p class="file">{{ $iteme->basename }}</p>
                 </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

@endforeach

Answer (score 0):

Привет тебе тут поможет отношение -  Один ко многим
1) Если у тебя не созданы модели то тебе нужно их создать 
Homework и HomeworkAnswer

2) Далее добавить в них взаимосвязи

**Один ко многим**

Отношение «один ко многим» используется для определения отношений, где одна модель владеет некоторым количеством других моделей. Примером отношения «один ко многим» является статья в блоге, которая имеет «много» комментариев. Как и другие отношения Eloquent вы можете смоделировать это отношение таким образом:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Homework extends Model
{
  /**
   * Получить ответы из домашки.
   */
  public function answers()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\HomeworkAnswer');
  }
}
```

Eloquent автоматически определяет столбец внешнего ключа в модели Comment. По соглашению, Eloquent возьмёт «snake case» названия владеющей модели плюс _id. Таким образом, для данного примера, Eloquent предполагает, что внешним ключом для модели HomeworkAnswer будет homework_id.

После определения отношения мы можем получить доступ к коллекции ответов, обратившись к свойству answers. Помните, что поскольку Eloquent поддерживает «динамические свойства», мы можем обращаться к функциям отношений, как если бы они были определены свойством модели:

```
$answers = App\Homework::find(1)->answers;

foreach ($answers as $answer) {
  //
}
```

Так как отношения служат и в качестве конструкторов запросов, можно добавлять дополнительные условия с помощью метода answers():

$answers = App\Homework::find(1)->answers()->where('title', 'foo')->first();
Можно указать внешний и локальный ключи, передав дополнительные параметры в метод hasMany():

```
return $this->hasMany('App\HomeworkAnswer', 'foreign_key');

return $this->hasMany('App\HomeworkAnswer', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

**Один ко многим (Обратное отношение)**

После получения доступа ко всем ответам домашки давай определим отношение, которое позволит ответу получить доступ к его домашке. Чтобы определить обратное отношение hasMany(), давайте определим функцию отношения на дочерней модели, которая вызывает метод belongsTo():

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class HomeworksAnswer extends Model
{
  /**
   * Получить домашку данного ответа.
   */
  public function homework()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Homework', 'foreign_key', 'other_key');
  }
}
```

После определения отношений мы можем получить модель Homework для HomeworksAnswer, обратившись к динамическому свойству homework:

```
$answer = App\HomeworkAnswer::find(1);

echo $answer->homework->title;
```

Comment: Спасибо, это понятно, как в цикле шаблона мне вывести ответы? еще один цикл или как?

Comment: Да можно еще один цикл, но я бы отдельно создал свой blade компонент. Или вынес все в слоты https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#components-and-slots

Comment: не разобрался с компонентами и слотами, а если 2-ой цикл вызывать то нужно в шаблоне вызывать модель?

Comment: Да тогда тебе надо передать на view $homeworks колекцию 

'@foreach($homeworks as $homework)
     '@foreach($homework->answers as $answer)

     '@endforeach
'@endforeach

Comment: а какой тогда будет запрос в котроллере? или он остается тем же? просто в моделях сделать связь?

Comment: Расспиши все таблицы которые сейчас учавствуют в твоем запросе и связи между ними, я помогу построить запрос через орм.

Comment: спасибо, отписал в ответе

Answer (score 0):

таблица связи между преподавателем и учеником и предмет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

таблица домашних заданий, которые формирует препод

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ответы ученика на домашнее задание, их может быть несколько

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и здесь я вывожу задание и ответы на него в колонке right ответы

```
@foreach($done as $iteme)
      <div class="item">
          <p class="title">{{ $iteme->theme }}</p>
          <div class="data-content">
             <div class="left">
                 <div class="text">{{ $iteme->replay }}</div>
                      <a href="{{ $iteme->file }}">{{ $iteme->filename }}</a>
                 </div>
             <div class="right all">
                 <div class="date-block">Дата сдачи: {{ $iteme->created_at }}</div>
                     <p class="file">Ответ</p>
                     <p class="file">Ответ два</p>
                 </div>
           </div>
       </div>
@endforeach
```